# behavior of static variable with inheritance

Tags: c++, static-members

I am asking this question for the discussion.

Suppose i have flowing class hierarchy

```
    class  A
    {
    public:
         static int varr;
    }

    class B : public A
    {

    }

    Class C : public A
    {
    }
```

If I create the Object of `B b1,b2,b3;` and `C c1,c2,c3;` and `A a1, a2;`

1.will  `varr` is shared across all the object mentioned above or there will be separate instance for different object?

2.if `b1` object change the value it will be reflected for `c1` object or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it will be shared accross all the instance of all derived(B,C) and base class(A)..

Only one instance for a static object will be created, and at all place that object will be refered. So if you change at one place it means change will be reflected at all location where its being refered.

Comment: So if I change the varr in one object say b1 and then when i access varr in c1 will it get the updated value right

Comment: Only one instance for a static object will be created, and at all place that object will be refered. So if you change at one place it means change will be reflected at all location where its being refered.

Comment: you can use templates if you want one per B,C and A

Answer (score 8):

Since `varr` is static (as opposed to a regular instance members), there is only one copy of it that belongs to the class itself, not an instance of it. `B::varr`,`C::varr` and `A::varr` all access the same variable, so there is no copy made for each inheriting class either.

Answer (score 1):

As static data members and methods are not per object, they are per class. that means one varr is there for class A.

 as class B & C are publically inherited from A, which makes B & C nothing but specialized A. (HAS IS-A RELATIONSHIP)

so all **A, B & C will share the same varr**

scenario would be different in case of **private inheritance**, where B & C would not be specialized A. And B & C will not have access to A::varr